# Firebug shows that Object Array has 1 more element

Tags: jquery

Newbie question. I'm pushing 3 objects into an array:

```js
var objarray = [{}];
objarray.push({"color":"red", "title":"ABC"});
objarray.push({"color":"blue", "title":"DEF"});
objarray.push({"color":"green", "title":"XYZ"});

console.log(objarray);
```

Firebug shows there are 4 elements. Does this only happen with Object arrays?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shows 4 objects as you create the array with an empty object in it - `[{}]`. Remove the inner braces and you'll have your three populated objects only:

```js
var objarray = []; // note: removed {}
objarray.push({"color":"red", "title":"ABC"});
objarray.push({"color":"blue", "title":"DEF"});
objarray.push({"color":"green", "title":"XYZ"});

console.log(objarray);
```